# Обход авторизации

Tags: php

У меня такая проблема, пользователи как то обходят авторизацию, подскажите, что делать?

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'conect_db.php';

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags(md5($_POST['password']+qwertyuiop));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'  AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(strlen($username)>0){
if(strlen($password)>0){
if($count==1){

$userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($result);
session_register("username");
session_register("password"); 
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo->username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo->id;
echo "<script>location.href='game.php?page=pokemons';</script>";

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ip='$ip' WHERE username='$username' ") or die ("Can't update");
mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET time=NOW() WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'  ") or die ("Can't update");
mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET online='1' WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'  ") or die ("Can't update");

}
else{  
echo "<script> alert('Не верное сочитание Логина и Пароля'); location.href='/index.php';</script>";
}
}
else{
echo "<script> alert('Вы не ввели Логин'); location.href='/index.php';</script>";
}
}
else{
echo "<script> alert('Вы не ввели Пароль'); location.href='/index.php';</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: *пошёл лезть в обход*

    strip_tags(md5($_POST['password']+qwertyuiop));
Зачем там вырезка тегов?

Кроме того, как вы поняли, что 
>пользователи как то обходят авторизацию

Comment: ха, а я спалил)) но не скажу. именно в этой строчке)

зы: 2 ошибки в ней

*это не считая лишнего strip_tags =)

Comment: Ага, да.
1. Строка 

    qwertyuiop

не в кавычках.
2. Конкатенация (соединение) строк в PHP происходит через ".", а не через "+", как в JS.

Comment: Ага, поэтому любой пароль обращается в 0, а `$password = md5((int)$_POST['password']+(int)null) = md5(0)`. Я вообще удивлен, что кто-то может(?) войти.

Comment: Угу, я попробовал, входит с любым паролем под пользователями.

Comment: Хм, это может значить только то, что [в базу пароль вставляется так же](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_lBXQVHyQ1VA/TNc8l-JJukI/AAAAAAAAArw/B6axr9ME8oY/s1600/jesus+face+palm.jpg)))

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что на него уже давно ответили в комментариях - но даже если написать ответ - то вряд ли автор вернется, чтобы выбрать его лучшим. Ценность же подобного разбора ошибок для будущих посетителей сомнительна.

Answer (score 3):

радость хакера:

```
"UPDATE users SET ip='$ip' WHERE username='$username' "
```

где $username ни разу не безопасный.